# Binding parameters in BoneCP

Tags: java, sql, connection-pooling, bonecp

BoneCP dont bind parameters in connectionHook.
Example:

```
 Query execute time limit exceeded [15s]. Query: SELECT pg_sleep(?);
```

Comment: Could you please provide an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing that it doesn't bind? At the moment, no-one can reproduce your issue and will have great difficulty in helping you

Comment: for better understanding please edit your question,

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved: illegal configuration. BoneCPConfig::logStatementsEnabled should be true